# Grails 3.3.2 extending "NavigableMapConfig" and overriding "get" method

Tags: grails, grails3

I have a scienario like to get dynamic config properties whenever user try to access properties from "`Holders`", for eg: "`Holder.config.testPropertyKey.userSpecific`".

I debugged this and it goes to method "get" of "NavigableMapConfig" class which implements "NavigableMap".

I tried to extend the "NavigableMapConfig" class to ovveride the "get" method and no luck.

If any one knows how to do this or need suggestion if i am in wrong path to achieve this.

Comment: I think your should be overriding `getAt()` method

Comment: @injecteer - You mean `getAt()` method from `NavigableMapConfig` class ?

Comment: yes..................

Comment: @injecteer - Still the same behaviour, is there any other way to do this ?

Comment: The thing is, that your class extension doesn't have any influence on the actual instance of `NavigableMapConfig` which is instantiated by Spring/Grails. One option would be to inject the new method into existing instance in run-time by meta-programming

Comment: @injecteer - Thank you for your suggestion. I already tried this. `NavigableMapConfig` is Abstract class because of this injected method via meta-programming is not working.

Comment: how and where have you tried that? It should be done in Application.groovy

Comment: In "Bootstrap.groovy" i tried to inject the "get" method. and "getAt" wont be get called all the time.

Comment: add the code to your question

Comment: `NavigableMapConfig.metaClass.get = { Object key ->`
        `CustomeMapConfig cmc = new CustomeMapConfig()`
        `return cmd.get(key)`
`}`

Comment: above code is in "BootStrap.groovy" file.

Comment: try putting like: `Holder.config.metaClass.getAt = { Object key -> ... }`. add some logging inside the closure so you can trace it

Comment: sure, i will try that now. It should be "Holders" right ?
Thanks.

Comment: @injecteer - I tried as you suggested, no luck.

Comment: @injecteer - Finally i made it work by using `Holders.config.static.getConfig = {}`.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for this:

In "BootStrap.groovy" file i overriden the "getConfig" for "Holders" method by the help of "Metaprogramming" as bellow:

```
    ExpandoMetaClass.enableGlobally();
    Holders.metaClass.static.getConfig = {
        <you code goes here...>
    }
```